# Symfony2 language keys for translation

Tags: symfony

We know this language keys

```
en_UK
en_EN
en
fr
fr_BR
```

In my project I want to support some major languages and I just want to use `en, fr, de` without the _BR or _UK part.

Will symfony2 detect if the users browser has fr_BR that it should use fr (french) to respond to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.. Symfony does not detect the user's browser language preferences automatically for a very good reason.

> This violates a fundamental rule of the Web: that a particular URL returns the same resource regardless of the user. To further muddy the problem, which version of the content would be indexed by search engines?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-locale-url

2.. Yes, you can use simply `en`, `fr` for your base languages. Symfony will use them accordingly. So in case of en_US the 'en' version would be used unless a translation file exists  with en_US in it. Read about it the following documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-fallback